# What are the differences between the game modes?

Tags: mini-metro

Mini Metro has three game modes - Normal, Endless, and Extreme (called Commuter, Scenic and Rush Hour in beta). I've played mostly on Normal, where difficulty increases until you fail, and the score gets uploaded. What are the differences between each of the game modes?

Comment: From its [app description on Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/287980/?snr=1_5_1100__1100): *Commuter for quick scored games, and Scenic for stress-free sandbox play*, but being a person who hasn't played & bought the game, I couldn't expand this as answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The below findings are based on personal gameplay of the Beta 15 version on Steam.

### In Normal *(previously Commuter)* Mode:

- The scoring timer in the top-right will measure **total passengers served**
- You recieve a budget increase (i.e. an upgrade) **at the end of every Sunday**, irrespective of how many passengers were served
- **If a station becomes overcrowded, you lose the game**
- The aim is to keep your system running for as long as possible before the inevitable overcrowding occurs

### In Endless *(previously Scenic)* Mode:

- The scoring timer in the top-right will measure **passengers served per day** (it has a timer, so you need to maintain the rate for a whole day)
- You receive a budget increase when you achieve **efficiency milestones**, i.e. you are maintaining a certain number of passengers served per day
- **If a station becomes overcrowded you *do not* lose the game** - this means you can play indefinitely
- The aim is to maximise efficiency, however, there is no loss condition so this is effectively a sandbox design mode

### In Extreme *(previously Rush Hour Mode)*:

- Scoring and budget increases are **as per Commuter Mode**
- **Line placements are permanent**; you can extend a line from its end, but you can't "un-hook" from an existing station or delete the line. This means that any closed-loop track is completely permanent.
- **Line upgrades are also permanent**; if you attach an additional train or carriage to a line, you can't then move it to another line ([cReddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/MiniMetro/comments/2t1gp0/beta_15_live_on_steam_added_rush_hour/cnuzhoq) where credit's due)
- Before a new station appears you'll see a **faded 'ghost'** of where it's going to pop up
- The aim is the same as commuter mode, but with the added challenge of being unable to rethink your design once it's laid

Comment: Also, I can't verify this, but it **feels** like the flow of passengers in Scenic is slower than Commuter, and faster in Rush Hour. Could be confirmation bias though.

Comment: Also, *Scenic* mode used to be *Zen* mode which was funnier and made it easier to intuit the rules changes if you got the cultural reference.

Comment: Can you explain more precisely how efficiency is calculated in Endless mode?  I assumed it was passengers served (i.e. dropped off at destination) in the past 24 hours, but I often see a passenger dropped off without the efficiency increasing.  I would think this would only happen if coincidentally some other passenger was served exactly 24 hours previously and so was no longer counted, but this seems to happen more often than that.  (Or should I ask this as a new question?)

Comment: I've noticed the same and I can't yet answer it- to me that sounds like a prime candidate for a new question :)