# What are the passenger bonus numbers?

Tags: mini-metro

When playing mini-metro at what passenger numbers do you get bonus items? I am trying to figure out how I can plan ahead and ect and this information could be extremely useful.

Comment: I don't suppose you mean the weekly bonus? This happens every week, not for passenger numbers. Or else they introduced a new feature, I haven't played in a while.

Answer (score 4):

To summarize some of the other answers and comments:

- **Normal**: You receive the bonus at the end of each In-Game Week
  *(after Sunday night is over, as shown on the clock in the upper-right corner)*
- **Endless**: You receive the bonus when you reach an Efficiency Milestone
  *(maintaining a certain number of passengers transported in a single day)*
- **Extreme**: *(the bonus is the same as Normal mode)*

A more complete explanation of each mode has already been written up in this excellent Q&A:
[What are the differences between the game modes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/202743/53249)

Answer (score 2):

It's not the numbers of passengers. You get the items with the In-Game Week system. You can see the progression of the week in the upper right corner. at the begining of each week, you get to choose a bonus Item.

Comment: It actually depends on the mode.  In endless mode, you get bonuses based on how many passengers you transport in a period of time.